# WithProofOfPossession() method missing from Microsoft.Identity.Client

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm writing a console application in dotnet core 3.1 and using the Microsoft.Identity.Client library 4.14, and I have the following code:

```
result = await App.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                        .WithProofOfPossession()
                        .ExecuteAsync();
```

But I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'WithProofOfPossession'`. I can access it in an Net45 app, but not in the netcoreapp3.1 app. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `.WithProofOfPossession()` => `.WithProofOfPosession()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported yet

From [their repository wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Proof-Of-Possession-(PoP)-tokens) (bold are mine):

> This is a new feature introduced in MSAL 4.8. **Currently it is supported only in .net 45** and for public client flows.

Also, not sure if this will also apply to you (because the method should be there anyway), but there was a bug (however fixed in 4.1 supposedly) which didn't expose the method:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1715